# Reading command into an Array in Bash

Tags: python, arrays, bash, sed, scripting

I need to read the following command outputs into an array, and then loop through that array within another command.

1. File hosts contains 2 IP addresses:

   - 192.168.3.78
   - 192.168.3.79

should read the output of *sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g" $hosts* into array sednames
*sednames=( $(sed ":a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g" $hosts) )*

I then have another loop to read through static ports (does work, as the ports are defined in the script). I want to then run each IP through this command with each port

m is supposed to be the array of IP's
i is the list of ports (which does work)

```
for m in "$sednames"  
do  
echo "m = $m"  
var=$(python -c "import socket; print(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM).connect_ex((\"$m\", $i)))")
```

The problem I am running into is that sednames and m only seems to contain the *first* ip, nothing more. Also, the python script barfs on the newline after .78, so that's the reasoning for the sed command to eliminate newlines to loop through each string in the array.

Comment: This is a problem with how you're iterating over the array, not with how you're reading into it. `for m in "$sednames"` ignores everything but the first element.

Comment: Use `for m in "${sednames[@]}"; do ...`

Comment: (that said, the way you're reading into the array is **also** an antipattern, but not for any reasons related to bugs you're hitting right now)

Comment: (See [BashFAQ #5 on "loading lines from a file or stream"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005#Loading_lines_from_a_file_or_stream) for the best-practices replacement for that code).

Comment: Thanks Charles, you were right. Instead of getting rid of the \n I just cut it off before using the value.